# Sequence Iteration with Exponent and Factorial Produces Unexpected Results

Tags: c#, algorithm, factorial

I attempted a simple task during learning but I'm stuck and have some weird results.
I have to write a simple method with 2 parameters 'x' and 'a'. Result of this method has to be sum of all x<sup>k</sup>/k! where k starts from 0 and goes to infinity, and 'a' is a parameter of accuracy.

[Here how it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mIIa3.png)

But I have no idea why when I'm putting Console.Write inside of loop, numbers are acting crazy and  [I have this for x = 2 and x = 6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C2xLx.png)

Also when I'm trying to put my code into method and use result there is nothing happening.
I have another method for mathematical factorial to calculate k!.

```
decimal wynik = 0;
int x = 2;
int a = 6;

for (int k = 1; k > 0; k++)
{
    if (Algorithms.Factorial(k) > 0)
    {
        wynik += Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(Math.Pow(x, k)) / 
                            Algorithms.Factorial(k), a);
    
        Console.WriteLine(wynik);
    }
}
    
Console.WriteLine(wynik);
```

and `Factorial` method

```
static public int Factorial(int n)
{
    int wynik = 1;
    
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        wynik *= i;
    }
    
    return wynik;
}
```

Of course I want to end with method and returning results but for practicing I'm working in Main method
Thanks a lot for help!

Comment: Welcome on SO.. I've a few questions: why do you round on *each term* you add and expect your result will be accurate in the end ?  that could be the cause of your issue, because that will cause an incremental error. Also it seems you're computing Factorial() twice, the test Factorial()>0 is not needed because a factorial is always positive.

Comment: factorial grows *very fast*, be careful with `int`: it's very easy to have an integer overflow: `13! > int.MaxValue`. Safier to work with `double`: `static public double Factorial(int n) {double wynik = 1.0; ...}`

Comment: Bec of overflow (now I know it) factorial become on some point 0 and program was crashing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Factorial grows *very fast*, please, look

```
  13! = 6227020800 > int.MaxValue
```

that's why returning `int` in `static public int Factorial(int n)` can well lead to *integer overflow* and strange results.
`x ** k` grows fast as well (though not *that* fast as factorial does). Let these large numbers *cancel* one another:

```
  double x = 2;

  double tolerance = 0.00001;

  double result = 1.0; // x**0 / 0! == 1 / 1 == 1
  double term = 1.0;

  for (int k = 1; term > tolerance; ++k) {
    // given term = (x ** (k - 1)) / (k - 1)! 
    // we can compute next term as
    term = term * x / k;

    result += term;
  } 

  // Let's have a look (in fact, you have Taylor serie for exp)
  Console.WriteLine($"actual   : {result} (+/- {tolerance:0.##############})";
  Console.WriteLine($"expected : {Math.Exp(x)}"");
```

**Outcome:**

```
actual   : 7.3890545668323435 (+/- 0.00001)
expected : 7.38905609893065
```

Comment: Nice opt. Guess that is 100.000 times faster too.

Comment: Thank you. I'm still not aware of some variable types limits. That helps a lot.